# How to map JSONObject - JSONObject["id"] not found

Tags: json

I cannot retrieve the information of the field customer.id from the json below:
{"date":"2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z","customer":{"id":"9999999999999999999"}}

I tried to map customer as JSONObject and get the key "id" but did not work
I tried to map customer as JSONObject and id as JSONObject but did not work

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"customer\":{\"id\":\"9999999999999999999\"},\"date\":\"2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z\"}");
JSONObject customer = new JSONObject(json.get("customer"));

// Show full string
System.out.println(json);
// Date returned without problems
System.out.println("date: "+json.get("date"));
// Customer object returend without problems
System.out.println("customerObject"+json.get("customer"));

// Trying to extract info - both failed
try{
    System.out.println("customerId: "+customer.getString("id"));
} catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.println("getString(id) failed: "+e.toString());
}
try{
    JSONObject id = new JSONObject(customer.get("id"));
} catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.println("customer.get(id) failed: "+e.toString());
}
```

ER:

```
{"date":"2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z","customer":{"id":"9999999999999999999"}}
date: 2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z
customerObject{"id":"9999999999999999999"}
customerId: 9999999999999999999
```

AR:

```
{"date":"2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z","customer":{"id":"9999999999999999999"}}
date: 2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z
customerObject{"id":"9999999999999999999"}
getString(id) failed: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not found.
customer.get(id) failed: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["id"] not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
When creating `JSONObject customer` add `toString()`

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"customer\":{\"id\":\"9999999999999999999\"},\"date\":\"2019-10-29T21:34:07.391Z\"}");
JSONObject customer = new JSONObject(json.get("customer").toString());

// Show full string
System.out.println(json);
// Date returned without problems
System.out.println("date: "+json.get("date"));
// Customer object returend without problems
System.out.println("customerObject"+json.get("customer"));

// Trying to extract info - both failed
try{
    System.out.println("customerId: "+customer.getString("id"));
} catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.println("getString(id) failed: "+e.toString());
}
try{
    JSONObject id = new JSONObject(customer.get("id"));
} catch (JSONException e){
    System.out.println("customer.get(id) failed: "+e.toString());
}
```